# Multiple @Input() decorators vs single @Input() decorator, in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

What is more efficient in Angular, transferring data into a child component with one @Input() decorator or more @Input() decorators?

I have two solutions: send all the data as one object into a child component or send it separately.

for example :

```
<child-component [data]="{ ...product, ...reviews }">
```

or

```
<child-component [product]="product data" [reviews]="reviews data" ...so on>.
```

**My question is about rendering speed. Which approach is more efficient for Angular rendering?**

Comment: Using the default strategy more inputs -> less speed, since how the change detection works. You could use the `onPush` strategy but it's then up to you decide when update the render. You could also uso a single subject to pass data and you don't have to worry about performances nor change detection.

Comment: Yes, finally, I did like your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of rendering speed and efficiency, there is generally no significant difference between using a single `@Input()` decorator with a complex object or using multiple `@Input()` decorators for individual properties. Angular's change detection mechanism is designed to efficiently handle updates to component inputs, regardless of whether they are bundled together or separated.

The choice between these two approaches should be based on other factors, such as code readability, maintainability, and the logical grouping of data. Let's explore both options:

1. Sending all data as one object into a child component using a single `@Input()` decorator:

```
<child-component [data]="{ ...product, ...reviews }">
```

Advantages:

- Code looks cleaner, especially if you have a large number of properties to pass to the child component.
- It can be easier to manage and pass around related data that belongs together.

2. Sending data separately using multiple `@Input()` decorators:

```
<child-component [product]="productData" [reviews]="reviewsData" ...so on>.
```

Advantages:

- Provides a clear separation of concerns for each property.
- If you have optional properties, it can be more convenient to pass them separately.

Ultimately, the decision should be based on the specific requirements and organization of your application. Consider the following factors:

1. **Readability and Maintainability**: Which approach makes the code more readable and easier to understand for other developers who might work on the project?
2. **Data Relationships**: Are the properties tightly related and always used together? In that case, bundling them into a single object might make sense.
3. **Component Reusability**: Consider if the child component can be reused in different contexts. Separating data into individual inputs might make it more versatile.
4. **Optional Properties**: If you have optional properties, it might be more practical to send them separately as individual `@Input()`.

Remember, the rendering performance difference between these approaches is negligible, so prioritize code readability and maintainability. If performance bottlenecks arise in the future, they are more likely to be related to other aspects of your application rather than the choice between these two `@Input()` approaches.

Answer (score 1):

generally it doesn't matter much how you pass your properties. However if you are using OnPush change detection strategy for child and this way of passing properties:

```
<child-component [data]="{somethin1, something2, ...soemthing3}">
```

then you are creating a new object with properties on every change detection in the parent - change detection would 100% visit child if it is hapenning in the parent, even if child's props didn't change (bc new object is created and passed via input)